# Will this be possible with Android wearable sdk

Tags: android, wear-os

I have been reading over the information regarding the wearables sdk and what it can do now and in the future.

My question is would the user be able to press something on the watch to alert my app of something on the smartphone or would the user have to speak into the watch or receive a notification from my app to interact with my smartphone app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to have "actions", so yes. For example, one of the actions of the Gmail app is that you can "Reply", "Reply all", etc, which would pop up on your phone.

According to the Android Wear developer website, the following code snippet would launch an intent on your handheld device:
  // Build an intent for an action to view a map
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + Uri.encode(location));
mapIntent.setData(geoUri);
PendingIntent mapPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mapIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventLocation)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map,
                getString(R.string.map), mapPendingIntent);

See:http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/creating.html for more info. See the section called "Add Action Buttons"

Comment: Thanks, but how would the user access/open say the gmail app for example?

Comment: See edited answer. I apologize for formatting errors as I edited on my phone.